# Get top 5 most popular values in mysql with where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project and I have a problem. I have a table named`friends`with three column`id`,`from_email`and`to_email`(it's a social networking site and "from_email" is the person that follows the "to_email"). I want a query to return the top 5 friends I follow according to the number of their followers. I know that the query for top 5 is:

```
SELECT 
   to_mail, 
   COUNT(*) AS friendsnumber
FROM 
   friends
GROUP BY 
   to_email
ORDER BY 
   friendsnumber DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Any ideas?

I would also like to return friends with the same number of followers ordered by their name. Is it possible?

Comment: the example SQL doesn't align at all with the columns mentioned in your question. please edit the SQL to use the same column/table names.

Comment: This code returns the 5 most popular values from the whole table,but I want this to return the 5 most popular people I follow (when my email is in from_email column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `COUNT(from_email)` instead of `COUNT(*)`; because you want to calculate the number of followers, which is represented by `from_email`.

Thus, your select clause would  be something like:

```
SELECT to_email, COUNT(from_email) as magnitude
```

as for getting the most popular people that you follow, you could use `IN` clause:

```
WHERE to_email IN (SELECT to_email FROM friends WHERE from_email='MY_EMAIL');
```

and about name, you shall join this query with the other table which contains the `name` value.

Since you've got the essentials now, I hope you can try to compose the full query on your own =)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was desperate!!

Answer (score 0):

Join again to the table for the 2nd tier count:

```
SELECT f1.to_email
FROM friends f1
JOIN friends f2 on f2.to_mail = f1.to_email
WHERE f1.from_email = 'myemail'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If an index is defined on `to_email`, this will perform very well.

Comment: I think I got a little bit confused. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Kon the first time `friends` is accessed (aliased as `f1`) it returns *your* followers ("your" specified via the `where` clause). The second time it is accessed (aliased as `f2`) it is joined to the first time's rows (via the `on` clause) return your *followers* followers. The count does the sorting. Does it work?

Comment: @Bohemian♦ apart from adding more explanation to this good query, I think you might want to revise it as well; it is producing a wrong result. OP wants `people that I follow`, not `the ones who follow me`